# Update End Date by adding duration to start date in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite

[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZga1.jpg) [Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ9dQ.jpg) [Create Table Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqQha.jpg) [Update Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEFvj.jpg)  I created table using SQLite Manager as mentioned below

```
CREATE TABLE activity (
    startdate INTEGER,
    duration  INTEGER,
    enddate   INTEGER
);
```

I attempt to update table using

```
UPDATE activity
   SET enddate =  date(startdate, '+duration' )
 WHERE enddate = 'enddate';
```

But doesn't work. How to solve the above? 
Thanks in advance for helping to solve my problem.

Comment: What is the format of your dates? Are they integers? Post sample data and the exact query that you try.

Comment: I updated my question above with images for more clearness Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
UPDATE activity 
SET enddate = date(startdate, duration || ' day')
```

I assume that `duration` is about days. 
If not you can change to `'month'` or `'year'`.
You can add a `WHERE` clause like:

```
WHERE startdate = '2020-01-01'
```